# ArcPy Create Point Along Line A Specified Distance From A Specified Point

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, point, line

In ArcGIS Basic I am trying to take a road polyline(one segment for the entire length of road) and get a point placed on the map a specified distance from an intersection. I have a layer of intersection points and the layer of roads. I need to tell it to place a point on the polyline where the starting intersection point is. Then travel the specified distance down the line and place a point for a sign. Any suggestions?

I am currently trying to write a script to select a road and points and create a temporary layer of each. Then from that temporary road I CreateRoutes_lr. Then take the intersection point and LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr. From locating the point I would like to take the "fmp" from distance as a variable. Is there any way to extract it?

Comment: This sounds like Linear Referencing.  Perhaps review [**What is Linear Referencing?**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000), try it out and revise your question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as PolyGeo mentioned, this is a linear referencing problem.  However, an easier workaround, in my opinion is to [buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) your intersections with the appropriate distance by using the distance field as the buffer distance.  Then [intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) the buffer with your road polylines.  Ensure that your output from the intersect tool is set to "point".  This will be your desired output.  However, you may get multipoint geometry and you may need to use the [Multipart to Singlepart tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/).

Comment: The results will be slightly different than true linear referencing for any roads that are not perfectly straight for the full specified distance from each intersection.

Comment: Agreed, if your roads have lots of bends within the buffer, you'll get undesirable results.